# Two Approaches to Calculating Combined Percentages

Tags: percentages

Upon some event there is a 50% chance that something has a 75% chance of happening. It is my understanding that there is a $.75/2 = .375$ probability of this.  Is there any way to know the probability if the first event does not occur?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We do not know what the chance is if the $50$% are not hit. Therefore, we cannot
 determine the actual chance.

Comment: I'm not sure this makes sense, maybe I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: You say : The chance is $50$% , that the chance is $75$%. So, in the half of the cases the chance is $75$%, but what is it in the other half of the cases ?

Answer (score 0):

Dispute it effectively by pointing out that 
$$
\frac{2}{8} + \frac{1}{8} = .375 \neq .325
$$